# moderate multiple unique facebook comment boxes?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-comments

Currently I have 10 different fb comment box on a single Webpage each having a unique url.

The problem is after adding this in to my head section.

```
<meta property="fb:admins" content="jayeshjain24ec,atneeiv" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.arrowlife.com" />
```

It should logically allow me to moderate all the comment boxes that are present on my single web page.But it does not.Infact it provides a comment box moderation feature only for the comment box present at the top of my page.

so eventually only one comment box get the Moderation feature out of 10.

Should I provide multiple og:url,What should I do.

MySite : http://www.arrowlife.com/

Comment: If you set all the comment boxes to the same URL, then they are in fact only one comment box, just displayed multiple times – because the comments are bound to the given URL.

Comment: @CBroe:well,i cannot compromise on that..i need to have different urls for different comments..so there is no solution to this?

Comment: Well do you have the same `og:url` set on all the pages you are pointing the comments plugin to? That would mean Facebook sees them as one URL.

Comment: I am pointing all my plugins on one single page..og url is kept same for now...the href="some url" is unique for all the diff comment boxes...i hope i am clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is a good case for the [Facebook Comment Moderation Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments) available to "Application Developers" and assigned "Moderators" for an "App".

This allows you to view all public comments from a website as well as moderate a queue of incoming comments.

A couple of links:

- [Recent Comments](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments?view=recent_comments)
- [Queue of comments for moderation](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments?view=recent_comments)

**Alternatively**
Try adding your moderators to the settings section of the [Facebook Comment Moderation Tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments) use the "Settings" link in top right of page. You then don't need the `fb:admins` property in the page.

Comment: the problem is i am having multiple comment boxes...each have url like this www.arrowlife.com?section=something1...www.arrowlife.com?section=something2...and so on..I do get a few comments on this link..but they are not for the url that i want

Comment: Added separate links for the two parts of the Facebook Comment Moderation Tool - making it clear that you can view "Recent Comments" and the "Moderation Queue"

For anything else provide a sample page that's not working.

Comment: :i cant expose my passwords.otherwise i would have shown you that that the links that you have added unfortunaely makes no difference.some more things i would like to tell is that the comments with url that i mentioned in the frst comment are not at all mentioned...these are comments coming from other comment boxes..on some diiferent page of the same website.You can view the page in case if you want to..its mentioned in the question

Comment: that was the very first thing i did...before putting up the question...that dint work too..

Comment: If you ensured that you are specifying a unique URL for each comment box, then I would [report a bug to Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs)